# Посоветуйте для изучения Шаблонов проектирования мануалы.

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Доброго времени суток.

Для саморазвития и правильного построения логики в проектах есть нужда в изучении шаблонов. Но по воле случая не у кого посоветоваться и показать свое творчество для критики и совета.

Не плохо бы узнать какие-то книги не с просто примерами а может и заданиями т.к 2 книги уже прочитал. 
Ну а если вообще хорошо то может какие-то задачи из вашего опыта(ссылкой на код буду рад).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что можно посмотреть по проектированию и шаблонам:

- [The Clean Architecture in PHP](https://leanpub.com/cleanphp) [En]
- [PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/33506422/) [Ru]
- [Pro PHP MVC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430241640) [En]
- Пополняемая коллекция туториалов по теме есть [здесь](https://github.com/marcelgsantos/learning-oop-in-php)
  [En]